# Peak bets in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a table of bets, amount(decimal) and created(timestamp), how can I select the peak amount bet within 24 hours (e.g. the 24 hours during which the biggest sum of bets was made and select that sum?)

I am experience with MySQL yet have no idea on how to approach the situation.

Comment: let's say that you have 100 bets. 50 from yesterday and 50 from today, you only need the highest bet from yesterday? What's the sum for?

Comment: I need the period with the highest sum not the highest amount of bets, there could be a single 200 bet or dozens of 0.0001 bets

Comment: The answer depends on the granularity you want. Do you want the max amount in 24 hours with 1 day granularity? (We don't care which hour had the max.) Do you want the max amount in 24 hours with 1 hour granularity? (We don't care which *minute* in that hour had the max.) Do you want the max in 24 hours with 1 minute granularity? (We don't care which *second* in that hour had the max.) Ditto for seconds, milliseconds, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll illustrate this with PostgreSQL, only because it's easier to generate the data quickly.

Create a table of buckets. This table will be used to group data. For this illustration, I'm using a granularity of one day. That is, I take "the peak amount bet within 24 hours" to mean the maximum amount bet during a 24 hour period that starts at midnight. (Different granularities require different buckets, but the principle is the same.)

```
create table buckets (
  bucket_start timestamp primary key,
  bucket_end timestamp unique
);

with starts as (
  select generate_series(timestamp '2013-01-01', timestamp '2013-01-31', '1 day') bucket_start
)
insert into buckets 
select bucket_start, bucket_start + interval '1 day' as bucket_end
from starts;
```

That SQL will give you a two-column table, with start and end buckets one day apart.  Now for a few bets. (Again, PostgreSQL. You'll have to give up enforcing the CHECK() constraint in MySQL, but you should include it anyway for documentation of your intent.)

```
create table bets (
  bet_created timestamp not null,
  bet_amount numeric(14, 2) not null
    check (bet_amount > 0),
  primary key (bet_created)
);

insert into bets values
('2013-01-01 00:00:01', 13.50), 
('2013-01-01 00:00:02', 13.50), 
('2013-01-02 00:00:01', 12.50), 
('2013-01-02 00:00:02', 11.50);
```

Now the amounts for every period covered by the table of buckets is just an outer join and a grouping.

```
select buckets.bucket_start, sum(coalesce(bet_amount, 0))
from bets 
right join buckets 
  on bets.bet_created between buckets.bucket_start and buckets.bucket_end
group by bucket_start 
order by bucket_start;

2013-01-01 00:00:00    27.00
2013-01-02 00:00:00    24.00
2013-01-03 00:00:00    0
...
```

To nip the max out of that set, you can sort descending, and take the first row. There are other ways.

```
select buckets.bucket_start, sum(coalesce(bet_amount, 0))
from bets 
right join buckets 
  on bets.bet_created between buckets.bucket_start and buckets.bucket_end
group by bucket_start 
order by sum desc
limit 1;

2013-01-01 00:00:00    27.00
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it with vanilla SQL? I am using maria db and have been trying to install postgresql just to run this single query.

Comment: All the sums return 0 for some reason